# A custom magento display of products

Tags: php, magento

I am currently developing a website using magento,

i am stuck though, i need to develop a page as such and i dont know if magento supports,

i need to have it looking like this
[image]

So As you can see,
i want to set it up so that category would a class, in this example it would be category 5th class, then i would have a subcategory called
example primary texts 5th

i want all of the sub categorys of 5th calss to be displayed on one page.

How would i go about displaying the information like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create custom template and custom function for add to cart. because normally magento has no feature to add different product to add cart at a time. 
now it will depends on you how you can customize magento.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom template (.phtml) for your School 5th class category and group products from child categories there as needed.